# create react app - `yarn build` on small EC2 server takes 100% CPU and makes it unresponsive

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build my react app on my server but running the `yarn build` command freezes the server and forces me to abort my session to be able to access it again.

Temporarily I'm just building locally and transferring the build folder to the server but this is obviously not ideal.

Is there a way to force reduced resource usage?

Comment: I suspect the culprit is memory usage, not CPU.  Try `/usr/bin/time -v yarn build` on your workstation, look at the "Maximum resident set size" number, and compare with the amount of RAM on the server.  You may not have much recourse except to pay more for a larger server with more RAM.

Comment: @NateEldredge ah yeah, that makes sense. Maybe this a good use case for a serverless function, seeing as I build infrequently and don't need the extra capacity.